# Can I use my phone as an emulator for VIsual Studio 2019?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, android-emulator, ide

I want to use my phone as an emulator for Visual Studio 2019. I want to use Visual Studio 2019 as an alternative for Android Studio because my pc can't handle it (I only have 4gb RAM). I tried coding in Visual Studio 2019 but I don't have an emulator. I tried downloading "Visual Studio Emulator for Android" but the software is not compatible with my pc (I don't know why). So, is it possible to use my phone as an emulator for Visual Studio 2019? and if not, what other alternative IDE can I use for our android app project?

Note: I'm still a student so I don't know much but I really appreciate the help

Comment: Your question is a bit missleading. If I understand correctly, you're not looking for an emulator for Visual Studio, but for your phone.

Comment: Sorry for the misunserstanding, but what I meant is I want to use my phone as the virtual device or like running my android app directly through my phone.

Comment: Yea, that was now clear from the answer, but the question confused me. I first thought you were trying to run Visual Studio _on your phone_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.

In order get debugging working I did the following.

Go to Settings > About phone and tap Build Number repeatedly until developer mode is enabled
Go into Settings > Developer options and turn USB debugging ON
Connect you phone to your PC via USB. I had to plug my phone into my PC's onboard USB port, not my USB hub as this did not work
You should be prompted to trust your PC (trust it)
Fire up Visual Studio
Open your solution and your device should now be available.
Side note: I have noticed that sometimes it also depends on the cable you use. If you still have no luck, perhaps try another cable.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It's working. The only problem is that you need to plug a phone that's compatible to the program or it won't work. I really thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome!!! and thank you for the acceptance of answer!!!